# Migration JBoss AS 7.1.1 to WildFly 8.2

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to migrate JBoss AS7 to WildFly 8.2 using Hibernate 4.3.7, PostgreSQL, JPA 2.1, JSF 2.2 and Primefaces. I'm connecting to my application normally. When I access page and try to persist data nothing happens, only loads the page and no error occurs.

```
package br.com.fio.sigaac.backing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import br.com.fio.sigaac.dao.AbstractDAO;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.dao.CursoDAO;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.dao.EventoDAO;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.dao.ProcEncerramentoDAO;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.dao.SituacaoFinalMatricDAO;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.Evento;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.FreqPtcLista;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.InstituicaoEnsino;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.ParticipanteEvento;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.TurmaComplEvento;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.to.TurmaEvento;
import br.com.fio.sigaac.util.JSFUtil;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class ProcessaEncEventoBacking {

private List<Evento> listaEventos;
private List<Evento> listaEventoFiltrado;
private List<TurmaEvento> listaTurmaEvento;
private List<TurmaComplEvento> listaSubTurma;
private List<InstituicaoEnsino> listaInstituicao;
private List<InstituicaoEnsino> listaInstituicaoFiltro;
private List<ParticipanteEvento> listaParticipanteMatriculado;
private List<ParticipanteEvento> listaPartMatricFiltrado;
private List<ParticipanteEvento> listaPalestrantes;
private List<FreqPtcLista> listaMovimentacaoParticipante;
private List<ParticipanteEvento> listaInscAgrupada;

private Evento evSalvar = new Evento();
private TurmaEvento turmaSalvar = new TurmaEvento();
private ParticipanteEvento partSelecionado = new ParticipanteEvento();
private InstituicaoEnsino ieSelecionada = new InstituicaoEnsino();
private FreqPtcLista freqPtc = new FreqPtcLista();

EventoDAO evDAO = new EventoDAO();
AbstractDAO abDAO = new AbstractDAO();
SituacaoFinalMatricDAO sDAO = new SituacaoFinalMatricDAO();
ProcEncerramentoDAO pDAO = new ProcEncerramentoDAO();
CursoDAO cursoDAO = new CursoDAO();

private Integer codEvento;
private Integer codTurmaEvento;
private Integer codIes = 9964;

public ProcessaEncEventoBacking() {
    criaListaIes();
    carregaIES();
}

public void processarEncerramento() {
    if (validarProcessamento()) {

        this.listaSubTurma = new ArrayList<TurmaComplEvento>(
                evDAO.buscaTurmaCompl(codTurmaEvento));

        if (listaSubTurma.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listaSubTurma.size(); i++) {
                pDAO.processarEncerramentoEvento(listaSubTurma.get(i)
                        .getSubTurma().getId());
            }
        }

        pDAO.processarEncerramentoEvento(turmaSalvar.getId());
        selecionaTurmaPorCodigo();
        criaListaParticipantesMatriculados(this.turmaSalvar.getId());
        JSFUtil.addInfoMessage("Operação realizada com sucesso.");

    }
}

public Boolean validarProcessamento() {

    if (this.turmaSalvar.getId() < 1) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Operação não efetuada. Selecione a turma do evento.");
        return false;
    }
    if (this.turmaSalvar.getControlaFreq() == null) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Operação não efetuada. Verifique os parâmetros da turma do evento.");
        return false;
    }

    if (turmaSalvar.getStatus().getId() == 6) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Operação não efetuada. O processamento de encerramento já foi realizado e não pode ser alterado.");
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("Status Turma: " + turmaSalvar.getStatus().getId());

    return true;
}

public void carregaIES() {
    try {
        if ((this.codIes != null) && (this.codIes > 0)) {
            this.ieSelecionada = this.cursoDAO
                    .buscaIESPorCodigo(this.codIes);
            if (this.ieSelecionada != null) {
                criaListaEventos();
            } else {
                setCodIes(null);
                setIeSelecionada(new InstituicaoEnsino());
                JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Nenhum registro encontrado para o código informado.");
            }
        } else {
            JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("O código informado é inválido.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void selecionaIes() {
    try {
        setCodIes(this.ieSelecionada.getId());
        criaListaEventos();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage("Erro ao selecionar IES. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void selecionaEventoPorCodigo() {

    if (codIes == null) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Informe o código da IES");
    } else if (codEvento == null) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Informe o código do evento.");
    } else {

        setEvSalvar(evDAO.buscarEventoParaEncPorCodigo(codIes, codEvento));

        if (evSalvar == null) {
            evSalvar = new Evento();
            JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Nenhum registro encontrado para o ID informado.");

        } else {
            criaListaTurmaPorEvento(evSalvar.getId());

        }
    }
}

public void selecionaTurmaPorCodigo() {

    if (codIes == null) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Informe o ID da instituição.");
    } else if (codTurmaEvento == null) {
        JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Informe o ID da turma.");
    } else {
        setTurmaSalvar(evDAO.buscaTurmaEvePorCodigo(codEvento,
                codTurmaEvento));
        if (turmaSalvar == null) {
            turmaSalvar = new TurmaEvento();
            JSFUtil.addWarnMessage("Nenhum registro encontrado para o ID informado.");
        } else {
            criaListaParticipantesMatriculados(turmaSalvar.getId());
            criaListaPalestrante(turmaSalvar.getId());
        }
    }

}

public void selecionarEvento() {

    setCodEvento(evSalvar.getId());
    criaListaTurmaPorEvento(evSalvar.getId());

}

public void selecionarTurmaEvento() {
    setCodTurmaEvento(turmaSalvar.getId());
    criaListaParticipantesMatriculados(turmaSalvar.getId());
    criaListaPalestrante(turmaSalvar.getId());
}

public void criaListaIes() {
    this.listaInstituicao = new ArrayList<InstituicaoEnsino>(
            this.cursoDAO.listaInstituicao());
}

public void criaListaTurmaPorEvento(Integer idEvento) {
    this.listaTurmaEvento = new ArrayList<TurmaEvento>(
            evDAO.buscaTurmaPorEvento(idEvento));
}

public void criaListaPalestrante(Integer idTurmaEvento) {
    this.listaPalestrantes = new ArrayList<ParticipanteEvento>(
            evDAO.listaPalestrantePorTurma(idTurmaEvento));
}

public void criaListaParticipantesMatriculados(Integer idTurmaEvento) {
    this.listaParticipanteMatriculado = new ArrayList<ParticipanteEvento>(
            evDAO.listaParticipanteMatriculadosPorEvento(idTurmaEvento));
}

public void criaListaEventos() {
    this.listaEventos = new ArrayList<Evento>(
            evDAO.buscarTodosEventosParaEnc(codIes));
}

public void criaListaMovimentacaoParticipante() {
    this.listaMovimentacaoParticipante = new ArrayList<FreqPtcLista>(
            pDAO.buscaMovimentacaoParticipante(
                    this.partSelecionado.getId(), this.turmaSalvar.getId()));

    System.out.println("Total: "
            + this.listaMovimentacaoParticipante.size());
}

public List<Evento> getListaEventos() {
    return this.listaEventos;
}

public void setListaEventos(List<Evento> listaEventos) {
    this.listaEventos = listaEventos;
}

public List<Evento> getListaEventoFiltrado() {
    return this.listaEventoFiltrado;
}

public void setListaEventoFiltrado(List<Evento> listaEventoFiltrado) {
    this.listaEventoFiltrado = listaEventoFiltrado;
}

public List<TurmaEvento> getListaTurmaEvento() {
    return this.listaTurmaEvento;
}

public void setListaTurmaEvento(List<TurmaEvento> listaTurmaEvento) {
    this.listaTurmaEvento = listaTurmaEvento;
}

public List<ParticipanteEvento> getListaParticipanteMatriculado() {
    return this.listaParticipanteMatriculado;
}

public void setListaParticipanteMatriculado(
        List<ParticipanteEvento> listaParticipanteMatriculado) {
    this.listaParticipanteMatriculado = listaParticipanteMatriculado;
}

public Evento getEvSalvar() {
    return this.evSalvar;
}

public void setEvSalvar(Evento evSalvar) {
    this.evSalvar = evSalvar;
}

public TurmaEvento getTurmaSalvar() {
    return this.turmaSalvar;
}

public void setTurmaSalvar(TurmaEvento turmaSalvar) {
    this.turmaSalvar = turmaSalvar;
}

public List<ParticipanteEvento> getListaPalestrantes() {
    return this.listaPalestrantes;
}

public void setListaPalestrantes(List<ParticipanteEvento> listaPalestrantes) {
    this.listaPalestrantes = listaPalestrantes;
}

public List<FreqPtcLista> getListaMovimentacaoParticipante() {
    return this.listaMovimentacaoParticipante;
}

public void setListaMovimentacaoParticipante(
        List<FreqPtcLista> listaMovimentacaoParticipante) {
    this.listaMovimentacaoParticipante = listaMovimentacaoParticipante;
}

public ParticipanteEvento getPartSelecionado() {
    return this.partSelecionado;
}

public void setPartSelecionado(ParticipanteEvento partSelecionado) {
    this.partSelecionado = partSelecionado;
}

public List<ParticipanteEvento> getListaPartMatricFiltrado() {
    return this.listaPartMatricFiltrado;
}

public void setListaPartMatricFiltrado(
        List<ParticipanteEvento> listaPartMatricFiltrado) {
    this.listaPartMatricFiltrado = listaPartMatricFiltrado;
}

public List<ParticipanteEvento> getListaInscAgrupada() {
    return this.listaInscAgrupada;
}

public void setListaInscAgrupada(List<ParticipanteEvento> listaInscAgrupada) {
    this.listaInscAgrupada = listaInscAgrupada;
}

public InstituicaoEnsino getIeSelecionada() {
    return ieSelecionada;
}

public void setIeSelecionada(InstituicaoEnsino ieSelecionada) {
    this.ieSelecionada = ieSelecionada;
}

public Integer getCodEvento() {
    return codEvento;
}

public void setCodEvento(Integer codEvento) {
    this.codEvento = codEvento;
}

public Integer getCodTurmaEvento() {
    return codTurmaEvento;
}

public void setCodTurmaEvento(Integer codTurmaEvento) {
    this.codTurmaEvento = codTurmaEvento;
}

public Integer getCodIes() {
    return codIes;
}

public void setCodIes(Integer codIes) {
    this.codIes = codIes;
}

public List<InstituicaoEnsino> getListaInstituicao() {
    return listaInstituicao;
}

public void setListaInstituicao(List<InstituicaoEnsino> listaInstituicao) {
    this.listaInstituicao = listaInstituicao;
}

public List<InstituicaoEnsino> getListaInstituicaoFiltro() {
    return listaInstituicaoFiltro;
}

public void setListaInstituicaoFiltro(
        List<InstituicaoEnsino> listaInstituicaoFiltro) {
    this.listaInstituicaoFiltro = listaInstituicaoFiltro;
}

public FreqPtcLista getFreqPtc() {
    return freqPtc;
}

public void setFreqPtc(FreqPtcLista freqPtc) {
    this.freqPtc = freqPtc;
}

public List<TurmaComplEvento> getListaSubTurma() {
    return listaSubTurma;
}

public void setListaSubTurma(List<TurmaComplEvento> listaSubTurma) {
    this.listaSubTurma = listaSubTurma;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Regards.
Renan.

Comment: only god knows without some code snippets and logs

Comment: Hi Paizo. I posted code example my bean. I think the problem be scope, but nothing conclusion. Regards.

Comment: Have a look at the Windup project, might reveal some changes needed.